# How does Google App Script to set a formula to Google sheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to put 2 formulas into google sheet through GAS. The problem is that it works for 1st formula, but failed on 2nd formula. I tried to manually keyin the formula in google sheet, it does work. I don't understand why it just not work for 2nd formula and always shows "#ERROR!" in the target cell (2,1).

```
sheet.getRange(3,1).setValue("=COUNT($B:$B)");
sheet.getRange(3,1).setBackground("yellow");
sheet.getRange(2,1).setFormula("=countif($C:$C,ʺNormal')");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula syntax is wrong

```
"=countif($C:$C,ʺNormal')"
```

- Error 1: `ʺ`
- Error 2: `'`

Replace the above formula by

```
'countif($C:$C,"Normal")'
```

---

Side note: To add a formula to a cell instead of `setValue` use `setFormula`